# Let $\{a_0,a_1,\dots\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and for any $k\geq1$, let $s_n=\sum^n_{k=0} a_{2k}$,

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{a_0,a_1,\dots\}$ be a sequence of real numbers and for  any $k\geq1$, let $s_n=\sum^n_{k=0} a_{2k}$, then

A . If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n$ exists , then $\sum^\infty_{m=0} a_{m}$ need not to be exist.

B. If  $\sum^\infty_{m=0} a_{m}$ exists, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n$  need not exist.

Comment: can u any give counter examples of this problems

Comment: sorry now i am edited ...

Answer (score 2):

A. Let $a_{2k} = \tfrac{1}{k^2}$ for $k > 0$ and $a_0 = 0$. Let $a_{2k+1} = \tfrac{1}{k}$. Then $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \tfrac{1}{k^2}$, and as $n\to\infty$, this series converges by the $p$-test. However, $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m \geq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tfrac{1}{k}$, and as the latter series diverges, so does $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m$.

B. Let $a_m = \tfrac{(-1)^m}{m}$ for $m > 0$ and $a_0=0$. Then $\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m$ converges by the alternating series test. However, $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{2k} = \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{k}$, which diverges as $n \to \infty$ (it's the harmonic series).

Comment: @Esperluet and Jon Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A. Let $a_n = n \cdot(n \mod 2)$. For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{2 n} = 0$ so $\lim\limits_{n \to +\infty} s_n$ exists (and is equal to $0$).
However, the series $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_m$ is divergent as $a_m$ does not converge to $0$.

B. Jon's example works well!